# Typescript: parse nested interface data with forEach()

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, parsing, foreach

`CountTargetsData` is an interface I use as a type to later parse JSON data. As seen below, the data has many nesting.

```
interface CountTargetsData {
  data: {
    [state: string]: {
      [date: string]: {
        [index: string]: { [id: string]: { [targets: string]: number } },
      },
    },
  };
}

const parseCounters = useCallback(
  async (responseDeploymentData: CountTargetsData) => {
    //WANT TO PARSE ID AND TARGETS HERE
  }
);
```

Given all the nests, how can I use the `forEach()` method to access the `id` and `targets` for each `CountTargetsData`?

Sample Data:

```
    "stateA": {
        "2016-06-03": [
            {
                "1200": {
                    "count_targets": 1,
                    "count_targets_excluded": 0,
                    "count_targets_pending": 0,
                    "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
                    "count_targets_completed": 0,
                    "count_targets_failed": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "2016-06-07": [
            {
                "1455": {
                    "count_targets": 1,
                    "count_targets_excluded": 0,
                    "count_targets_pending": 0,
                    "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
                    "count_targets_completed": 1,
                    "count_targets_failed": 0
                }
            }
        ]
         
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have an example of the data? do you just want a flattened array of id, target pairs? or do you need  some other context?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Your type doesn't match the example data you provided

It should be:

```
interface CountTargetsData {
  data: {
    [state: string]: {
      [date: string]: ({
        [index: string]: {
          [id: string]: {
            [targets: string]: number
          }
        },
      })[],
    },
  };
}
```

```js
const data = {
  "stateA": {
    "2016-06-03": [{
      "1200": {
        "count_targets": 1,
        "count_targets_excluded": 0,
        "count_targets_pending": 0,
        "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
        "count_targets_completed": 0,
        "count_targets_failed": 1
      }
    }],
    "2016-06-07": [{
      "1455": {
        "count_targets": 1,
        "count_targets_excluded": 0,
        "count_targets_pending": 0,
        "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
        "count_targets_completed": 1,
        "count_targets_failed": 0
      }
    }]
  }
}

Object.entries(data).forEach(([state, value]) => {
  Object.entries(value).forEach(([date, value]) => {
    value.forEach(obj => {
      Object.entries(obj).forEach(([id, value]) => {
        Object.entries(value).forEach(([target, value]) => {
          console.log(state, date, id, target, value)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

**Old answer**

You can't use `.forEach` directly as the nested data is stored as objects and not arrays.

Try using `Object.entries` / `Object.values` first or use `for..of` loop:

```
const parseCounters = useCallback(
    async (
      responseDeploymentData: CountTargetsData
    ) => {
      Object.values(responseDeploymentData.data).forEach(state => {
        Object.values(state).forEach(date => {
          // and so on
        })
      })
  }
```

```
const parseCounters = useCallback(
    async (
      responseDeploymentData: CountTargetsData
    ) => {
      for (const state of responseDeploymentData.data) {
        for (const date of state) {
          // and so on
        }
      }
  }
```

Think about using recursion or DFS algorithm

Comment: both of your proposed suggestions did not work: 1) when I tried to assign variables or even `console.log` in any nesting of the `forEach()`, nothing would happen; 2) for the this one I get error: `Type '{ [state: string]: { [date: string]: { [index: string]: { [id: string]: { [targets: string]: number; }; }; }; }; }' is not an array type or a string type or does not have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

Comment: both of your proposed suggestions did not work: 1) when I tried to assign variables or even `console.log` in any nesting of the `forEach()`, nothing would happen; 2) for the this one I get error: Type '{ [state: string]: { [date: string]: { [index: string]: { [id: string]: { [targets: string]: number; }; }; }; }; }' is not an array type or a string type or does not have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

Comment: Can you add an example object in the post?

Comment: @KonradLinowski I just updated the post to include sample data to show its format

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your data doesn't match the type.

Comment: @KonradLinowski do you suggest I remove the `index` nesting?